# To compare tags with the same name in xml file with other tag in other xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I have two XML files. At the first one I have some devices those are already in the DB (tags **ipAddress** are important).
Second XML file contains device/devices those should be added if they are not at the DB (Post request).

I have already code for comparing two XML file if they have just one device (one tag with ipAddress ).

FILE1(contains 30 devices. I added just 2 for example).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <queryResponse last="34" first="0" count="35" type="Devices" responseType="listEntityInstances" requestUrl="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices?.full=true" rootUrl="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data">
  <entity dtoType="devicesDTO" type="Devices" url="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices/200">
     <devicesDTO displayName="201200" id="200">
       <deviceName>NEW</deviceName>
       <deviceType>Cisco Switch</deviceType>
       <ipAddress>10.66.12.128</ipAddress>
     </devicesDTO>
   </entity>
   <entity dtoType="devicesDTO" type="Devices" url="https://hostname/webacs/api/v1/data/Devices/201">
     <devicesDTO displayName="201201" id="201">
       <deviceName>NEW-SWW</deviceName>
       <deviceType>Cisco Switch</deviceType>
       <ipAddress>10.66.12.127</ipAddress>
     </devicesDTO>
   </entity>
 </queryResponse>
```

FILE2 (it could be one or more devices)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <devicesImport>
    <devices>
      <device>
         <ipAddress>10.66.0.8</ipAddress>
         <networkMask>24</networkMask>
        <snmpWriteCommunity>labor</snmpWriteCommunity>
      <udfs>
         <udf>
            <name>LaborTest</name>
         </udf>
      </udfs>
   </device>
  </devices>
  </devicesImport>
   <devicesImport>
    <devices>
      <device>
         <ipAddress>10.66.0.9</ipAddress>
         <networkMask>24</networkMask>
        <snmpWriteCommunity>labor</snmpWriteCommunity>
      <udfs>
         <udf>
            <name>LaborTest</name>
         </udf>
      </udfs>
   </devices>
  </devices>
 </devicesImport>
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;


 my $xml1 = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('FILE1.xml');
 my $xml2 = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('FILE2.xml');

 #$xml2->findnodes( './ipAddress/*'); # I tried to cover all ipAddress from FILE1

  #Next Try to do it other way
  #foreach $xml1->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text {
  #foreach $xml2->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text {


    # I compare here just one tag from both files (it works if my file contains just one device)
    if ( $xml1->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text
    eq $xml2->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text ) 

   {
     print "IP matches\n";
   }
```

I also tried

```
    if (( $xml1->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text
    eq $xml2->get_xpath( '//ipAddress', 0 )->text ) 
    for $xml2->findnodes  ('//ipAddress'));
```

but it doesn't works.

Comment: Do those entries in your list actually correlate?  They don't have the same names or IPs?

Comment: Also -the first 'file' appears to be two separate XML documents. Is that deliberate?

Comment: no, it should not be two separate XML documents, was a mistake

Comment: Yes, they don't have the same names or IPs, it is just example...but at this time it is about just IPs, because my 'file2' contains just IPs and no names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the thing here is `get_xpath` locates nodes matching a certain criteria.

If you've definitely got stuff in the same order, you can just get two lists of `get_xpath` responses and iterate them.

But I don't think that's a safe assumption in `XML` - a device might be missing.

So instead, you need to write a `search` - `get_xpath` can do this too.

There's a couple of problems with your input though - `FILE1.xml` you've got there, is actually two separate XML documents. There's no `root` tag between both, and there's an `<?xml` declaration twice.

So you need to transform it slightly to make  it a single doc (or parse both seperately). Likewise with `FILE2.xml` - you've got two `</devices>` tags at the end (one should be `</device>`). Check you're using valid XML, because all sorts of things break if you don't:

However for illustration purposes, I'll assume they're a single document:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml1 = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('FILE1.xml');
my $xml2 = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('FILE2.xml');

foreach my $device ( $xml2->get_xpath('//device') ) {
   my $ip_addr = $device->first_child_text('ipAddress');
   print "Looking for $ip_addr\n";
   if ( my $search = $xml1->get_xpath("//ipAddress[string()=\"$ip_addr\"]") )
   {
      print "Found: ", $search->parent->first_child_text('deviceName'), "\n";
   }
   else {
      print "Didn't find match for: ",
        $device->get_xpath( './/name', 0 )->text, "\n";
   }
}
```

Now, there's none found here, because your IPs don't match in your two files.

`XML::Twig` has limitations in what it can do with `xpath` so it's worth checking the [quick reference guide](http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/quick_ref.html) (this is where XML::LibXML` comes into it's own - it's more fully featured)